# how can I filter nmap results for multiple strings and output to file?

Tags: awk, nmap

2I wanted to get a host list of linux servers on my network using nmap, but I'm not sure how to filter the results based on multiple strings. So I'm using something like:

```
nmap -sT -R --dns-servers 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2 -p 22 192.168.1.0/24
```

which gives me the results but of course it's also showing every IP with the closed ports. How can I use logic with awk so that if it finds an IP with a hostname AND finds that the lines below have 'tcp open' it will spit those two lines to an output file?

The typical input to use from nmap would look like:

```
Interesting ports on server.domain.com (192.168.1.1):
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Interesting ports on server2.domain.com (192.168.1.2):
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp closed  ssh
```

but this would be for every single IP that is scanned, so I'm trying to find a way to have a file with only the hostname and IP "if" it shows as 'tcp open' from the nmap command above. Basically giving you a file with:

```
server.domain.com (192.168.1.1)
```

So that I only get the server name and IP if SSH is actually listening on port 22

Comment: Edit your question to show a few lines of testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I sort of got this working by using the above nmap command to generate the output to a file, raw.txt. Then created a new file called filter.awk with:

   BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
{ print $1 ", " $2 ", " $3 }

and then ran:
    awk -f filter.awk raw.txt > newfile.txt

and then filtered it again for '/domain.com/ && /open/' > file

and that worked, but there must be a way to clean this up a bit. :)

Comment: No doubt there is and if you do what I asked then someone here would be able to show you how.

Comment: @Ed Morton: the question already had the input command, the output from the nmap and how I wanted to change that to have the output below that using awk. Not sure how I can clarify this more for you

Comment: slightly better using both grep and awk:
grep -B3 open raw.txt | awk '/domain\.com/' > hostlist

This will find anything in the nmap output with the 'open' string and then print the first line so that seems to be okay

Comment: The input command is irrelevant, we need sample input for the command you are trying to write (i.e. the output from nntp or whatever it is). You had posted one block of input, we need to see a few diverse and representative blocks to understand the commonalities and variances in the input. You've now posted 2 blocks which is better but still not good. You've posted 1 line of output from that input withno explanation of why 1 input block seems to be represented in the output but not the other. Post 5 blocks of input and the EXACT output you want given that input.

Comment: Use the -oX parameter of nmap to export the result as XML and later parse the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample input and the sample output posted, something like this could work:

```
awk '/^Interesting/ {
       domain = $(NF-1)
       ip = substr($NF, 0, length($NF) - 1)
     }
     $2 == "open" {print domain, ip}' file
```

This works like this:

- If a line starts with "Interesting", then the second to last field is stored as the domain, and the last field (minus the trailing colon) is stored as the ip.
- If it finds a line where the second token is "open", then it prints the domain and ip found previously.

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the help